# Restore IDM and uTorrent state/settings after updating Windows

Tags: windows-7, restore, utorrent, download-manager

I want to change my Windows. So all programs deleted. I have many links in my IDM and uTorrent for download. Well , most of them are in download, for example one of them in 30% download and another in 50% and other links are just like it.

Is there any place in IDM or uTorrent that defined this status of downloads? Because my destination download is somewhere else. Lets say what is on my mind, I think there must be a file that shows this link is in 10% , this one in 90%, and if I import, the program know the file that downloaded before. After, it can resume downloads from (in my examples) 10% and 90%.

If it's clear what I want, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the IDM & uTorrent folders in `%appdata%`, copy it elsewhere, (re-)install Windows, run IDM & uTorrent & then exit the apps.

Now copy the folders back to the `%appdata%` folder and you'll be able to resume the downloads

Comment: it seems your answer is correct... let me try it on my laptop (it's safer) then mark your answer.

Comment: i do what you said. i copy files from appdata\roaming\... folders. then remove idm, and install it again and copy files into that path. but nothing happens. is there any other way or tip for this work!?

Comment: which files did you copy? @hos

Comment: I don't know about IDM, but if it doesn't save *all* state and settings in that folder and uses the registry for something then that might explain why it failed to work. uTorrent though saves everything to `%AppData%\uTorrent` and so this procedure definitely works with it (I can confirm).

Comment: guys i just change my windows, and it work for my torrents. thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure about IDM, but it just worked for uTorrent 2.2.1 stable. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Open "Options->Save To" dialog ("Options->Downloads" for old versions) and look what folder is set in "Temporary directory" field (arrow 1 on the image). Save this folder somewhere in order to use it later. Do the same for each category download folder to save your completed downloads. To see path for each category folder select them in "Category" listbox (arrow 2 on the image).

   Please note that by default `AppData` folder (`Application Data` for Windows XP) is hidden. Please read here how to see hidden folders.
2. Export `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\DownloadManager` registry key and also save it. Please read here how to work with system registry.
3. After your system reinstall or on a new computer import registry key that you have saved. Then copy IDM temporary folder and all category download folders under same paths that they had on initial system.

Then run IDM. If you done everything correct, IDM will use your old settings. You should see a list of your downloads and be able to resume unfinished downloads.

Answer (score 0):

In utorrent,
Copy your unfinished download file to any other drive.

After format change your download destination to new location.

Try redowload the torrent. The recheck process will be back and resume will be done.